# Dual of LP representation of graph coloring

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, coloring, integer-programming, binary-programming

I have found a representation of the *graph coloring* problem as an ILP. Given a graph $G = (V, E)$.

Let $C$ represent the set of colors. Let $w_c$ be a binary variable that is $1$ if the color $c$ is used and $0$ otherwise.
Let $x_{v,c}$ be a binary variable that is $1$ if the vertex $v$ is colored by $c$.

**ILP**
$$
\min \sum_{c \in C} w_c \\
\text{s.t} \sum_{c \in C} x_{v, c} = 1 \; \forall \; v \in V \\
x_{u, c} + x_{v, c} \leq w_c \; \forall \; (u, v) \in E, \; \forall \; c \in C \\
x_{v,c}, w_c \in \{0, 1\} \; \forall v \in V, \; \forall \; c \in C
$$

I want to find the dual of the LP relaxation.

The problem I think, is that there are multiple binary values instead of one which I am used to for linear programming. I would assume that for the LP relaxation, the constraint for both $x_{v, c}$ and $w_c$ is set to greater than or equal to $0$, that is the LP relaxation will be:

$$
\min \sum_{c \in C} w_c \\
\text{s.t} \sum_{c \in C} x_{v, c} = 1 \; \forall \; v \in V \\
x_{u, c} + x_{v, c} \leq w_c \; \forall \; (u, v) \in E, \; \forall \; c \in C \\
1 \geq x_{v,c}, w_c \geq 0 \; \forall v \in V, \; \forall \; c \in C
$$

From here I am not really sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: You need to add a constraint that $w_c \le 1$ for all $c \in C$, or its equivalent. Otherwise, the second LP has an integer solution that the first LP does not have: set $w_1$ to $2$ and $x_{v,1} = 1$ for all $v \in V$, and set all other variables to $0$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for pointing that out! Edited it now

Comment: In fact, the dual will be simpler if you do *not* impose an upper bound on $x$.  The upper bound of $1$ on $x$ is already implied by nonnegativity and the $=1$ constraint.

Comment: @RobPratt that makes sense. I still dont see how the dual is constructed tho.. It is probably my lack of understanding of the dual formulation, but I am used to there being two constraints $Ax \geq b$ and $x \geq 0$ and then the dual formulation has constraints involving $A^T$. In this case however, I don't see how $A$ and $b$ should be

Comment: Arthur Benjamin's [S-O-B method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2132755) is useful for obtaining the dual LP.